# WKWebview load local html file with query parameter not work?

Tags: ios, swift, angular, wkwebview

Local URL here:

```
file:///Users/XXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/96C7E920-4220-4E51-9E0C-5F075F653AED/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B3CFF26D-AC05-4430-A6A9-69D46A93C193/ABC.app/ABC/index.html/loadTargetPage?pageName=homePage
```

I have a local html file, and I want to add query parameter when I load request.
But when I load request with local url, and wkwebview delegate function `webviewDidFinish` not work.
I just see this function `webviewDidStartProvisionalNavigation` called.
I think wkwebview load fail. What's wrong about this?

```
let parameters = ["pageName": "homePage"]
webview.load(appendURLString: "/loadTargetPage", queryParameters: parameters)

public func load(appendURLString: String? = nil, queryParameters: [String: String]? = nil){
 
            if let bundle = Bundle(identifier: APP_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER), var path = bundle.path(forResource: LOCAL_WEB_NAME, ofType: LOCAL_WEB_FILES_TYPE, inDirectory: LOCAL_WEB_FILES_DOCUMENT_PATH), FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path) {
                
                if let appendURLString = appendURLString {
                    path = path + appendURLString
                }

                let url: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

                if let queryParameter = queryParameters?.first {
                    let queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: queryParameter.key, value: queryParameter.value)]
                    if let finalURL = url.appending(queryItems) {
                        self.webview?.load(URLRequest(url: finalURL))
                    }
                    return
                }

                self.webview?.load(URLRequest(url: url))

                
            } else {
                
                self.hybridSDKDelegate?.showAlertView?(title: "HybridSDK_ERROR", message: "html path error", confirmBtnTitle: "OK", cancelBtnTitle: nil)
            }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that file URI scheme supports query parameters.
So you can use "?pageName=homePage" when fetching rest api's.
But not when fetching local files.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023 this now works as expected. I am able to pass any arbitrary query parameter(s) to my locally copied html assets like so:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "dist/index", ofType: "html") {
  let indexUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path, isDirectory: false)
    .appending(queryItems: [
      URLQueryItem(name: "native", value: "true")
    ])
  webView.loadFileURL(indexUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: indexUrl)
}
```